# How can I separate route files?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route file in my project and it is called from my app with these lines:

```
var index = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/', index);
```

But I need to separate the route file, and I'm trying to do this:

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var user = require('./routes/user');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/user', user);
```

In route **user.js** I put the service that I need to access from the client. But it's not working. I don't know what is wrong, I am a beginner in Node.js.

The request returns:

```
GET /user/find 304 4.203 ms - -
```

And user.js file is:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/user/find',function(req, res){
   Object.find(function(err, s){
       if(err) res.send(err);
       res.json(s);
    });     

});

module.exports = router;
```

*This request works well on **index.js**

Comment: It would be useful to post the contents of user.js needed to recreate the issue, and expand on how it is not working. Node crashes? Blank page? Network error?

Comment: your problem lies on the required files...

Comment: "router.get('/user/find',function(req, res){" change for "router.get('/find',function(req, res){". It´s an incremental path definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put user router under `/user` route, and in your user router you defined `app.get('/user/find')`, so the actual path would be `/user/user/find`, you need to remove the `user` prefix in router

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/find',function(req, res){
   Object.find(function(err, s){
       if(err) res.send(err);
       res.json(s);
   });     

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: So, i'm trying this to call the route:

`$scope.showUsers = function(){
  $http.get('/user/find')
  .success(function(data){
   $scope.users = data;
  })
  .error(function(data){
   alert(data);
  });
 }`

But is returning error 304

Comment: The error was that i put a `/` for the **index.js**, when the route was looking for /user, it wore the *index.js* instead of **user.js**

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this can be:

index.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var route1 = require('./route1')
var route2 = require('./route2')

app.use('/', route1);
app.use('/hello', route2);


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

route1.js

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello route1');
})

module.exports = router
```

route2.js

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello route2');
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: So i think my problem is on client side... How client knows what router will receive the request?

Comment: The client has no way of knowing which path the server will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to include a `module.exports = router` at the end of each of your route files?

Your route files should be set up thusly:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get("/example", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Hello");
});
module.exports = router;
```